# Twitter button without the <a> tag

Tags: twitter, twitter-button

My twitter button is inside a div, which is inside an `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> 
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="<?php $url = get_post_thumbnail_id(); $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($url,'medium'); $url = $url[0]; echo $url; ?>">
        <div class="social-buttons">
            <div class="wrapper facebook">
                <div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper google">
                <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" align="center"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper twitter">
                <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Tweet</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

The problem is that because the twitter button is an `<a>` tag, my parent (original) `<a>` tag doesn't work. Is there a way to integrate the twitter button without the default `<a>` code?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you even have to outer `a` element? You can not nest such “interactive” elements in HTML, and for a good reason. Just get rid of it, it makes little to no sense to have it there in the first place.

Comment: It's because it's also linking the post image. Basically I have the social buttons on the right corner of the image. When users click the image, it'll redirect them to somewhere else. However if they go on the corner, they can click the buttons. I've edited my question to make it more understandable.

Comment: Well then place them outside of the post link in the source code, and position them over it using CSS.